# Large Android project, code base increases and looks ugly.

Tags: android, performance, codebase

We are working on a project in android.
Our project has following functionality:
1. Make rest calls.
2. Save data to database.
3. Show data on Ui.
4. Many other android features.

We use Retrofit, ActiveAndroid.

Our project has many Activities and Fragments, so  the code base is increasing drastically.

- Can anyone suggest what should be the best way to handle this problem. Or any link or video which gives details about this things.
- What are the best practices to avoid increasing code base at the save time maintain efficiency.

Comment: Im guessing you are using the MVC model?

Comment: Not Completely the MVC model for short off.. Like Activity loads data from server and save to database, fragment loads data from database and displays..